# How to make daemon.json log-driver configuration optionally?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, daemon

I have server docker container A that sends logs to docker container B(logstash).
When logstash is down and i restart container A, it will not start because it will try to connect to logstash port 12201 and will fail.
Error: "failed to initialize logging driver gelf cannot connect to gelf endpoint"

How to make daemon.json configuration optional?
How to make docker container A start even if it will not be able to connect to container B on start?

mode: non-blocking is not working

daemon.json-
**{
"log-driver":"gelf",
"log-opts":{
"gelf-adress":"tcp://10.10.0.1:12201",
"mode":"non-blocking",
"max-buffer-size":"8m"
}
}**

Thank you.

Comment: @matic1123 Do you mean mode:non-blocking worked with udp and not with tcp?

Comment: Docker container would start even tho Graylog service was down with UDP mode, so it was not checking if it was running. Atleast in our case.